# Changing a value in array with references

Tags: php, reference

```
 //below example now works thanks to Alexander.
```

I am trying to use array_walk_recursive, and I can't get the original value in the array to change. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

```
public function setConstants()
{
    array_walk_recursive($this->_arr, function(&$item, $key2){

        $constants = get_defined_constants(true);

        foreach($constants["user"] as $key => $value)
        {
            if (strstr($item, $key)){
                $item = str_replace($key,$value,&$item); //EDITED FOR VALIDITY, WORKS.
            }
        }
    });
    return $this->_arr;
}
```

I am trying to traverse the multidemensional array "_arr" using array_walk_recursive, and for every constant thats part of constants[user] (which is an array as well) i want to replace the equivalent value in _arr if the string matches the constant name

Comment: What exactly you want to do? explain in example

Comment: i explained it, but Alexander got what I meant :) thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are not assigning the replaced value appropriately.

```
$item = str_replace($key,$value,$item);
```

Instead of:

```
str_replace($key,$value,&$item);
```

Should be enough.